# What to do when an answer I'm about to accept disappears?

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I asked this question: [screen mirroring - How to display camera image on second Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/239083/how-to-display-camera-image-on-second-android-device), and shortly after, it received an answer.

I tried the suggestion, it worked, I upvoted the answer, and then I waited the customary 24 hours.
Life was good.

Today I went to accept it as the solution to the problem, and the answer had disappeared.
There are no other answers.

Even if I don't get an answer to the obvious "what happened" question, I'd still like to know what is appropriate on my part.

Should I post the solution and then accept it, even though it was originally given by a different user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question was a link-only answer. Here's a copy of that:

> See this video "Cast Android screen to Android": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UoZadzMnok

That answer, in its *entirety*, contained only a link to a video. Not even to a text-based resource! Such posts are classified as Very Low Quality (VLQ) posts. They are more like throwing a bone. Lazily (more like reluctantly) written. Such answers might prove to be helpful to some users, but they are usually very bad and often require a lot of efforts on part of a reader to extract usefulness from such links. As such, they are *usually* voted out by community members to be deleted or are instantly deleted by moderators.

That answer was deleted by me. Given the activity of the user on the whole Stack Exchange network the user is unlikely to return here and fix their answer. Should the user returns, they can always post a new and a better answer. So no harm done.

As for you, if the link helped you out then *please do* post a self-answer and accept it, along with the steps that you found useful from that video. If you just post a link too, then your answer won't be any different than from the aforesaid user, and might be flagged by Community bot or community members as VLQ.

Comment: FWIW, I also have let the OP of the answer known about the link-only answer and encouraged them to fix it before it was deleted. They can still fix it, and we'll undelete it when needed.

Comment: I understand and agree with what happened.  It's somewhat ironic though that in two days no one else has given an answer and I was lucky to catch that answer when I did.  Had it not been for that inappropriate answer, I still wouldn't have a solution.

Comment: @AndrewT., I *have* posted a self-answer, but if the original answer is improved and reposted, I'll get rid of mine.